# Model List to ViewModel List in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a DBContext "StatusDBContext", a Model "Status_T" with some(n) properties and a corresponding ViewModel "Status" with few of the Model properties. I am using Entity Framework with code first from database.

DBContext:

```
namespace xxx.Areas.SysParam.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class StatusDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public StatusDbContext()
            : base("name=xxxConnectionString")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<STATUS_T> STATUS_T { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<STATUS_T>().ToTable("STATUS_T");
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace xxx.Areas.SysParam.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("STATUS_T")]
    public partial class STATUS_T
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string TYPE { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public byte STATUS { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string LANG_CODE { get; set; }

        public DateTime UPD_DTIME { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DELETE_DTIME { get; set; }

        public short? VER_NO { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public string STAT_USE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using xxx.Areas.SysParam.Models;

namespace xxx.Areas.SysParam.ViewModels
{
    public class Status
    {
        [Display(Name = "Status ID")]
        public byte STATUS { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type")]
        public string TYPE { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "In Use")]
        public string STAT_USE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Before introducing ViewModel the Controller looked like:

```
public ActionResult StatusView()
{
    List<Models.STATUS_T> StatusList = new List<Models.STATUS_T>();

    using (var status = new Models.StatusDbContext())
    {
        StatusList = Status.STATUS_T.ToList();
    }
    return View(StatusList);
}
```

Now I have two questions.

1) As I googled about Model, ViewModel and DataAnnotations its somewhat clear that DataAnnotations should be added to ViewModel but in Code First from Existing DB the Models are generated with few DataAnnotations so what will be the best practice here, to copy properties from Model to ViewModel and add more DataAnnotations whenever required?

2) How to replace Model with ViewModel in Controller code?

Help will be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Updated: Controller:

```
public ActionResult DWPStatusView()
{
    var DWPStatusList = new List<ViewModels.DWPStatus>();

    using (var DWPStatus = new Models.DWPStatusDbContext())
    {
        DWPStatusList = DWPStatus.DWP_STATUS_T.ToList().Select(p => new ViewModels.DWPStatus(p)).ToList();
    }
    return View(DWPStatusList);
}
```

Comment: 1) Model is object usually represent DB Entity, ViewModel is object that is send to front-end, there is also BindingModel, this is data that is send with HTTP request.
2) You probably don't wana replace Models with ViewModel, you just wana map between. For object mapping I recommend AutoMapper - http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Yes, best practise is to create separate view model class and copy there necessary properties from DB model, because:

- may happen that DB model have unwanted properties for view
- view model may need additional properties and adding them to DB model 
  is not good practise

View model usually have validation data annotations attributes, so better keep them also separate from DB annotations.

2.

```
public ActionResult StatusView()
{
    var statusList = new List<ViewModels.Status>();

    using (var status = new Models.StatusDbContext())
    {
        statusList = Status.STATUS_T.ToList().Select(p => new ViewModels.Status {
            Property1 = p.Property1,
            Property2 = p.Property2,
            ...
        }).ToList();
    }
    return View(statusList);
}
```

You can place property mapping into view model constructor, then selecting data will look next:

```
statusList = Status.STATUS_T.ToList().Select(p => new ViewModels.Status(p)).ToList();
```

**Update:** and view model:

```
public class Status
{
    public Status(){}
    public Status(Models.STATUS_T model)
    {
        //here comes mapping
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gene, I added the mapping to the ViewModel constructor but now when I am trying to create the View its giving me following error : There was an error running the selected code generator:

**'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'xxx.Areas.SystemParameters.ViewModels.Status'. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Status: : EntityType 'Status' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Status: EntityType: EntitySet 'Status' is based on type 'Status' that has no keys defined.'**

Comment: @NikhilGupta Your view model class should have also parameterless constructor

Comment: as per your answer I needed to add mapping to my View model constructor that can only b done when I pass Status_T class to the constructor and now u have mentioned to have a parameterless constructor. Sorry m a bit confused. Could you please explain in your answer how the mappings should be like and how should the parameterless consructure b like...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103392/discussion-between-nikhil-gupta-and-gene-r).

Comment: Can you make this a generic function.